# Uniformly continuous entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-continuity, cauchy-integral-formula, entire-functions

> Find all entire functions that are uniformly continuous on the complex plane.

I think the answer must be the the linear polynomials, but nor sure, since neither of polynomials of degree greater than 1 or transcendental entire function are uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{C}.$

Given $\epsilon >o$, there exists $\delta>0$ for any $z_1, z_2$ such that $|z_1-z_2|\leq \delta $ then we have $|f(z_1)-f(z_0)|\leq \epsilon.$

Let write the taylor expansion of $f(z)$ around point $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
$$
f(z)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)z^n}{n!}.
$$
so if for $z_1, z_2$ we have $|z_1-z_2|\leq \delta $, we get

$$
|f(z_1)-f(z_2)| \le
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}|z_1^n-z^n_2|}{n!}
$$

Intuitively, I can see that $n=1,0$ to have a uniformly continuous function, but I might be wrong. I appreciate any help.

Comment: $f(z)-f(z+\delta)$ is bounded...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich which is an entire function, so by Liouville theorem, it must be bounded.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Does that lead to a super quick proof? I thought of using UC to get  $|f(z)| \le A+B|z|$ and then using the well known result that an entire function with that growth must be linear.

Comment: @zhw. In fact $f(z)-f((z+h)$ is bounded for every $h$ with $|h|<\delta$; in particular $f'(h)=f'(0)$ for all  such $h$, so $f'$ is constant.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Right, very nice.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I was thinking if we fix $z$ and consider the Taylor series around point $z$, it implies that $f^{(n)}(z)$ is bounded. Since $  f(z)-f(z+\delta)=k$, where $k $ is consonant,  all $f^{(n)}(z)$ are bounded entire functions ( for $n\geq 1$), so they are constant. In particular $f'(z)$ must be constant which implies $f(z)$ is linear.